# Unable to determine xdebug entry point for php 7.0 and apache

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php7, xdebug

I'm trying to install `xdebug` ... or even uninstall it.

It's not loading properly, but for the life of me I can't get it to uninstall.

I tried to reinstall it several times only to eventually realize that every time I did, it would increase the length of the errors. So somewhere there's old, accruing config hanging around.

I've grepped all of `/etc` and `/usr` for `xdebug`, nothing.

Every time I `pecl install xdebug` each section gets longer and it adds a section.

Through `phpinfo` I cans see that all the secondary `.ini` files are in `/etc` so I shouldn't be missing anything.

Here's the errors

```
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function
[Fri Feb 03 00:32:20.293423 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9490] AH00173: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.0.2.15. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Fri Feb 03 00:32:20.368835 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9490] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Feb 03 00:32:20.370983 2017] [core:notice] [pid 9490] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: Your installation is a complete mess. Blow it away and start over. This time, install only one version of PHP.

Comment: I figured out what it was.  I had to completely stop apache and start it again.  What I was doing was effective.